# How to Retrieve the Request Object in the Bootstrap File? Zend Framework/PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

Anybody know how to retrieve the request object in the bootstrap file of zend framework mvc. Just trying to repopulate a form that is included on every page if you know a better way of doing this instead of using the bootstrap file then let me know? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend doing it in the bootstrap file. The purpose of the bootstrap file is very specific in the Zend Application.

Why don't you try using a plugin that will run during the pre-Dispatch. That is before the dispatching of the Controller Action of your choice?

You can check the documentation on the plugins topic.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks I just looked up how to get the request from the frontcontroller.  Appreciate the idea of using a plugin will implement it.